# Python + Tornado - Quick and clean solution to transform PeriodicCallback() function

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

As I understand it, Tornado is single threaded and executes each request synchronously, even though it handles them asynchronously (still confused on that bit).

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):
        #do something
        ...

        #periodically call function to get image and send it to client
        self.callback = PeriodicCallback(self.get_image_screencap, 800)
        self.callback.start()


    def get_image_screencap(self):
        #take image
        ...

        #send it to client
        self.write_message(self.str_img)

    def on_close(self):
        self.callback.stop()
        print 'connection closed'


application = tornado.web.Application([
(r'/', WebSocketHandler),
])

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8080)
main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
main_loop.start()
```

Result after 2.clients join on server

- 1.client receive image
- 2.client receive image
- 1.client receive image
- 2.client receive image

First callback depend on another callback etc...

What is the best solution for this? I need independent function (get_image_screencap - this function is blocking, i need take image from different mobiles in parallel execution) for all clients. Should i use new threads and semaphores on methods (write ...), which are not thread safe ?